# Spring Dataflow and Yarn: How to set properties properly?

Tags: spring, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, spring-cloud-dataflow

How can one change the default appdeployappmaster properties ?

When I'm trying to deploy an application through Spring DataFlow YARN. I registered my app, created a stream, and click the "deploy" button. When doing so, I get the following error :

> [XNIO-2 task-2] WARN  o.s.c.d.s.c.StreamDeploymentController - Exception when deploying the app StreamAppDefinition [streamName=histo, name=my-app, registeredAppName=my-app, properties={spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=log, spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=histo}]: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.yarn.YarnSystemException: Invalid host name: local host is: (unknown); destination host is: "null":8032; java.net.UnknownHostException; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/UnknownHost; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: Invalid host name: local host is: (unknown); destination host is: "null":8032; java.net.UnknownHostException; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/UnknownHost

As you can see, the deployer is unable to find the "Resource Manager" URI, Although it is well found when the Spring DataFlow Server starts.
So I only get the problem at the deployment time.

Which property should I set to fix this issue, and where would I do that ?

**EDIT 1:**
Following Janne Valkealahti's answer, I added the following properties in `/dataflow/apps/stream/app/servers.yml`, relaunched the server, and tried to re-deploy my stream.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    dataflow:
      yarn:
        version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    deployer:
      yarn:
        version: 1.0.2.RELEASE
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: kafka.my-domain.com:9092
          zkNodes: zookeeper.my-domain.com:2181/node
  # Configured for Hadoop single-node running on localhost. Replace with property values reflecting your
  # actual Hadoop cluster when running in a distributed environment.
  hadoop:
    fsUri: hdfs://mapr.my-domain.com/referentiel/ca_category_2014/
    resourceManagerHost: mapr.my-domain.com
    resourceManagerPort: 8032
    resourceManagerSchedulerAddress: mapr.my-domain.com:8030
  session:
    store-type: none
```

I still get the exact same message.

PS: I'm not using Ambari, I'd like to understand how it works manually first.

**EDIT 2:**
I solved the problem adding the `-Dspring.config.location` VM arg on the DataFlow Server. The given configuration is passed to the deployer, and the application is effectively deployed.

I'll write an answer for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I needed to add the `-Dspring.config.location` JVM arg to make it work. `-Dspring.config.location` should point to the file containing the YARN configuration, i.e.:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    dataflow:
      yarn:
        version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    deployer:
      yarn:
        version: 1.0.2.RELEASE
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: kafka.my-domain.com:9092
          zkNodes: zookeeper.my-domain.com:2181/node
  # Configured for Hadoop single-node running on localhost. Replace with property values reflecting your
  # actual Hadoop cluster when running in a distributed environment.
  hadoop:
    fsUri: hdfs://mapr.my-domain.com/referentiel/ca_category_2014/
    resourceManagerHost: mapr.my-domain.com
    resourceManagerPort: 8032
    resourceManagerSchedulerAddress: mapr.my-domain.com:8030
  session:
    store-type: none
```

This configuration is then passed to the deployer app (`appdeployerappmaster` if I get it right).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell if your installation was based on ambari or normal manual YARN install so I assume it was a latter(manual).

I think a problem is that in distribution you use the `config/servers.yml` has a wrong setting for `resourceManagerHost` as it defaults to `localhost`. This file is distribute only once into hdfs when streams are launched. If you have changed it after you redeploy/create stream, app in hdfs directory will not get updated. On default this file in hdfs is `/dataflow/apps/stream/app/servers.yml`.

This error makes sense as also dataflow yarn server controlling whole stuff also needs access to yarn resource manager to submit apps. Settings for server also comes from a same `servers.yml` file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried what you proposed, and sadly it doesn't change a thing. I edited my question to add the steps I tried. Do you see anything wrong with what I've done ?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the solution. Thanks for your help